# How to get the value of access token in ASP.NET Core MVC OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc, google-oauth

In Visual Studio 2017RC I created ASP.NET Core MVC app with individual user accounts and successfully completed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins tutorial to attach Google authentication. I'm now logged in via my Google account.

All I did was adding a few lines to the autogenerated code (in Configure method of Startup.cs):

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions
{
    ClientId = "xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    ClientSecret = "xxxx",
    Scope = { "email", "openid" }
});
```

I now need to get the value of access token which was issued by Google (and stored in cookies by the app). I'll then use it to generate XOAuth2 key to access Google services. For instance, in HomeController's About method (auto-generated by the standard wizard) I want to display the number of unread emails in my inbox. With XOAuth2 key, I can log in my Gmail and proceed from here.

How can I get this token?
- Do I need to store access token in database during initial logging in via Google? If so, any clues how this can be done in the standard wizard-generated ASP.NET Core MVC app?
- Or, maybe I can always read the access token from cookies? If so, how?

Preferably, I'd read it from cookies (it's anyway there) and avoid duplicating this info in database but not sure if this approach is feasible (i.e. if it can be decrypted).

I did this for ASP.NET MVC once but in ASP.NET Core MVC things have changed a lot, the legacy code is of no use anymore.

Answer (score 9):

OK, found it. SaveTokens property does the trick.

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions
{
    ClientId = "xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    ClientSecret = "xxxx",
    Scope = { "email", "openid" },
    SaveTokens = true,
    AccessType = "offline"
});
```

I can then get access token in AccountController.ExternalLoginCallback

```
var token = info.AuthenticationTokens.Single(x => x.Name == "access_token").Value;
```

Comment: what type is info in your example?

Comment: I don't remember exactly but I believe it's `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ExternalLoginInfo`.

Comment: Where do you get info from?

Comment: @Murray It's all in AccountController.ExternalLoginCallback. For instance, there is `var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();` line.

Comment: I haven't touched this for more than a year. Maybe they indeed changed things since then once again.

Comment: is there any common place to store the token after the retrieval

Comment: I used AspNetUserClaims table for this. When writing this article https://afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs/#OAuth2RegularAccountsWebApps.html I created ExternalProviders library which did this. I wrote it a helper for MailBee.NET mail library but it's actually not dependent on it and can be used separately.